# change the style of a dynamic text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this page where a text might change, and each part has it's color. 
I could have done it with PHP, but it kinda seemed like it's not practical. 
I tried to read some javascript and jquery, thought they would help, but nothing.

so, is there a practical way to do this ?

here's my code:

index.php

```
 <?php  
      $k=1;

      if($k==0){ 
          echo"<h class=client> Client </h>";
      }
      else if($k==1){
        echo
      "<h class=designer> Designer</h>" ;     
      } 
      else if($k==2){
       echo
      "<h class=developer> Developer</h>";
      }    
      else if($k==3){
                echo 
        "<h class=designer> Designer</h> & <h class=developer> Developer</h>";     
        }

    ?>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
.client {
  color: blue;
}
.designer {
  color: yellow;
}
.developer {
  color: red;
}
```

so the output should be a a Blue "`client`" or Yellow "`designer`" or Red "`developer`", or a Yellow "`designer`" and a Black "`&`" and a Yellow "`designer`", depending on the `k`.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I can't say it's a problem. well, I'm wondering if there's another way to do this, a practical method or something. because what I did doesn't seem right..

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy but how is your dynamic text been created??

Comment: @Danko I connect to a database and copy some valuer to variable 'k' and check k's valuers, for each valuer I show some text, just as you see in my php code.

Comment: If you have designed the database, you could try storing a more meaningful value for k. i.e. instead of k as an int, k = "designer", then you could just echo k's value `echo "<h class='". $k ."'>". ucfirst($k) ."</h>"`

Comment: @Daniel and if it comes to 'Designer & Developer', I want each one to be with a different color while '&' with the color black only, how can I do that !?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. I've added an answer which suggests a solution to that problem.

Comment: @Daniel that's a good solution, I thought about it only today. it might take more space but maybe it's the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of javascript is overkill, you should probably just stick to a php only solution.

As I mentioned in the comments, you could alter your database design so that it compliments your application.

It's hard to say the best way to do this without knowing in detail the workings of you program - but as I mentioned, as an example you could store a more semantic value for $k (i.e. "client" or "designer" or "designer,developer"), or you could have 4 different booleans for each of your "titles" - but again the best way really depends on how you will need to interact with this information across the application as a whole.

A quick implementation for the first suggestion could look like this:

```
// $k = "designer,developer";

if (strpos($k, ',') !== FALSE){
   $titles = explode(",",$k);
   $output = "";
   foreach($titles as $title){
      $output .= "<h class='". $title ."'>". ucfirst($title) ."</h> &amp; ";
   }
   echo rtrim($output, ' &amp; ');
} else {
echo "<h class='". $k ."'>". ucfirst($k) ."</h>";
}
```

Comment: I see.. though it didn't answer my wonder but it's a good practice. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Classes are written in quotes.

Try:

```
<h class='developer'> Developer</h>
```

Comment: Classes without quotes, this is working.? http://jsfiddle.net/rmJ7C/ Did I misunderstand anything.?

Comment: the classes are working fine, and the colors change.

Comment: In html5 isn't necessary the quotes arround attributes http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tags/f/quotes-required-html-5-attributes.htm @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: quotes aren't necessary, but there's no reason why you shouldn't have them. it's good practice.

Comment: so guys, if there in Javascript or in Jquery some way to do what I did with the text changing their colors ? because this doesn't seem practical.